# Is there a composite output stream in the Ruby standard library or a gem?

Tags: ruby, outputstream

I'd like to create an object that can be configured with an arbitrary set of output streams (e.g. `STDOUT`, an open file, a `StringIO`) such that I can write to this object once, and have it write output to all the configured output streams.

Does such a thing exist? It would probably not be difficult to write but if it's already out there that would be better.

So something like...

```
log_file = File.open('my.log', 'w')
strio = StringIO.new
outputter = CompositeOutputStream.new(log_file, strio, STDOUT)
outputter << "I can be found in all 3 output streams."
...
log_file.close
# do something with strio.string
```

Comment: Not in the standard library AFIK. Don't know wheter someone already invented a Gem for this. Maybe you can do so, and contribute it to the community?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that this is a possibility, and I already have contributed several open source gems. I don't know if this one will be worth my time though, especially since some loggers do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a library that deals directly with streams, but for logging there is https://github.com/rocketjob/semantic_logger which is able to multiplex, batch, async etc.